# Error with floating numbers with variables

Tags: bash, awk

I have a command like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo how many GİBs
read n
echo $n GİBs = $a GBs

a=$(awk "BEGIN {print 1.073741824*$n; exit}")
```

But gives output like this:

```
how many GİBs
12
12 GİBs = GBs
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: You need to set `a` first, *then* print it. Also, I'd recommend double-quoting the strings to be printed (e.g. `$n GİBs = $a GBs`) and passing `n` in to `awk` with the `-v` option rather than just including it directly. And: use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: On a side note: You can also do: `printf %.9f $((1073741824 * n))e-9`

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone! :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use awk's `-v` to set an **awk** variable.   e.g. to set awk's `n` to the same value as bash's `$n`, `-v n="$n"`.

```
$ n=10
$ a=$(awk -v n="$n" 'BEGIN{ print  1.073741824*n; exit}')
$ echo $a
10.7374
```

Why do it this way, rather than use bash variables directly inside a double-quoted awk script?

Because it eliminates an entire class of potential issues that can cause problems in either your bash script OR your awk script OR both.

Comment: I did it:
`echo "how many GİBs"

read n

echo "$n GİBs = $(awk -v n="$n" 'BEGIN{ print  1.073741824*n; exit}') GBs"`